# Magento 2 - Get cart item qty change in Javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript, cart, quantity

I have a javascript file that loads when the page loads. This file defines two variables (one for the shopping cart items and one for the count).

This script also contains a `subscribe` that fires whenever the cart is updated.

When I add items to the cart, remove items from the cart or update the cart, this `subscribe` is hit and I am able to execute logic inside there.

This is fine for most however when a user changes the `qty` of an item in the cart, I can never get the previous `qty`.

```
var cart = customerData.get('cart');

    // Define variables to check against inside the subscribe
    var count = cart().summary_count;
    var currentItems = [...cart().items];

    // Watch the cart
    cart.subscribe(function () {
        // If the count has changed
        if (cart().summary_count !== count) {  
                for(let i =0; i < cart().summary_count; i++){
                    var foundItem = currentItems.find(x => x.product_id == cart().items[i].product_id);
                    var currentItem = cart().items[i];

                    // Both of these values are the same
                    if(foundItem.qty < currentItem.qty){
                        var qtyChange = currentItem.qty - foundItem.qty;
                    }
                }
        }

        // Set the count to the new value
        count = cart().summary_count;

        // Set the new currentItems array
        currentItems = cart().items;
    });
```

The `cart().summary_count` updates but the qty against the item updates in both the duplicated items array defined outside the subscribe as well as the `cart().items` array (which I'd expect).

I have noticed that the value for qty in the array defined outside the subscribe changes to a string and the `cart().items` version of the qty is an int.

Below is a screenshot of what I am seeing in dev tools. I have updated the qty in the cart for item_id 269

[image: screenshot of devtools]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

- The problem appears to be with the data type of the qty attribute in
  the currentItems array. When you receive the qty value from
  foundItem, it is regarded as a string, whereas it is treated as an
  integer in currentItem.
- To fix this, change the quantity value to an integer before
  conducting the comparison.

Check this code,

```
 var cart = customerData.get('cart');

// Define variables to check against inside the subscribe
var count = cart().summary_count;
var currentItems = [...cart().items];

// Watch the cart
cart.subscribe(function () {
    // If the count has changed
    if (cart().summary_count !== count) {  
        for (let i = 0; i < cart().summary_count; i++) {
            var foundItem = currentItems.find(x => x.product_id === cart().items[i].product_id);
            var currentItem = cart().items[i];

            // Convert qty values to integers
            var foundItemQty = parseInt(foundItem.qty, 10);
            var currentItemQty = currentItem.qty;

            if (foundItemQty < currentItemQty) {
                var qtyChange = currentItemQty - foundItemQty;
                // Perform logic with qtyChange
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the count to the new value
    count = cart().summary_count;

    // Set the new currentItems array
    currentItems = cart().items;
});
```

Comment: My question is tho. The value for `qty` in the array defined outside the `subscribe` (`currentItems`) updates to the new `qty` value. This array is only declared on page load. It means that when I am comparing the values, they are the same. I expected the array declared outside the `susbcribe` to retain the old qty until I set that array to the new array (shown in the last line of the code snippet)